# Как узнать размер двумерного указателя?

Tags: c++, указатели

Не могу найти как узнать размер двумерного указателя. Я передаю указатель arrKeyRate

```
...
    int row_arr_KeyRate = listRate.count();
        QString **arrKeyRate = new QString* [row_arr_KeyRate];
        int column_arr_KeyRate = 3;
        for (int i=0; i<row_arr_KeyRate;i++) {
            arrKeyRate[i] = new QString[column_arr_KeyRate];
        }

        for(int j=0; j<row_arr_KeyRate;j++) {
            arrKeyRate[j][0]=listDataFrom.at(j);
            arrKeyRate[j][1]=listDataTo.at(j);
            arrKeyRate[j][2]=listRate.at(j);
        }
        emit(dataReadyRead(arrKeyRate));
```

...
Тут пытаюсь узнать его размер так `sizeof(arrKeyRate)/sizeof(*arrKeyRate)` и так `arrKeyRate[j]->count()` и так `arrKeyRate[j]->size()`

```
...
    void MainWindow::dataUploader(QString **arrKeyRate)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=sizeof(arrKeyRate)/sizeof(*arrKeyRate);j++){
          qDebug()<<"MainWindow"<<arrKeyRate[j][0]<<arrKeyRate[j][1]<<arrKeyRate[j][2]<<sizeof(arrKeyRate)/sizeof(*arrKeyRate)<<sizeof(arrKeyRate)<<sizeof(*arrKeyRate);
        }
    }
...
```

Но он выводиться не весь так как размер не правильный.

Comment: `arrKeyRate` не массив, а указатель. Размер массива, на первый элемент которого он указывает, следует передать явно. А еще лучше - использовать подходящий контейнер, вектор или что там в qt есть.

Comment: @VTT передать явно это как? Так- emit(dataReadyRead(&arrKeyRate)); И как узнать размер указателя? Можно пример ?

Comment: явно - значит "отдельным числом"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Размер указателя вы и получаете:

```
sizeof(arrKeyRate) // должно вернуть 8 для 64-битного компилятора
```

(это размер `QString**` указателя).

```
sizeof(*arrKeyRate)
```

(а это размер `QString*` указателя). Кстати, их размер одинаковый.

Размер массива по указателю вы в `c++` никак не получите. И логично же. Даже если взглянуть на "популярную" функцию в `c` - точку входа в программу - можно обнаружить такую сигнатуру:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Первым параметром идет "длина" массива (длина не в байтах, а в "штуках"), вторым - сам массив (кстати, можно вместо `char* argv[]` писать `char** argv`, смысл практически не меняется).

Если вам нужно передавать куда-то двухмерный массив, вам необходимо также явно передать и длины его измерений, к примеру:

```
void MainWindow::dataUploader(int lengthX, int lengthY, QString **arrKeyRate) { ... }
```

Вы можете заметить, что хранить длину массива отдельно от самого массива - не особо-то удобно. И на помощь приходят вектора:

```
std::vector<std::vector<QString>> arrKeyRate(row_arr_KeyRate);
```

Ну и так далее - смысл понятен. Тогда для вектора вы сможете получать длину так:

```
int lengthX = arrKeyRate.size();
int lengthY = arrKeyRate[0].size();
```

Кстати, вторая строчка выполнится безопасно лишь в том случае, если в векторе 1 и больше подвекторов, так как мы берем длину первого подвектора. Ну с этим тоже разберетесь, думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вообше то у вас есть размер массива(вы сначала правильно писали, а размер любого указателья фиксированный)
 `arrKeyRate` содержит адрес первого элемента массива из `row_arr_KeyRate` указателей, которые указывают на массив из   `int column_arr_KeyRate = 3;` элементов. Так что ваш массив имеет размер

```
 row_arr_KeyRate` * column_arr_KeyRate
```